# Unable to access object property of state object in state modification method (TypeError)

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, properties

I'm working on a text analyzer in jQuery that returns word count, unique word count, average word length, and average sentence length.

I had it working (at least halfway, up to the unique word count functionality) before I realized my structure was horrible. So I refactored it...and now I'm having trouble getting it to work at all.

On line 65, I'm getting `TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null`. This is in reference to `state.sentences`, which when I console.log, I get `null`. I just noticed that when I type in a full sentence as my input, that doesn't come up (and it logs the sentence correctly), but it's still not rendering the content to the DOM.

What am I doing wrong here? Something about the way I'm trying to access the `state` object, obviously -- but what, exactly, is beyond me.

Here is the index.js:

```
'use strict'

// state object

var state = {
    text: "",
    words: [],
    uniqueWords: [],
    sentences: [],
    wordLengths: [],
    sentenceLengths: [],
    wordCount: 0,
    uniqueWordCount: 0,
    averageWordLength: 0,
    averageSentenceLength: 0
}


//state modification functions

var getText = function(state) {
    state.text = $('#user-text').val()
}

var getWords = function(state) {
    state.words = state.text.match(/[^_\W]+/g)
    //need to also change all uppercase to lowercase
}

var getSentences = function(state) {
    state.sentences = state.text.match( /[^\.!\?]+[\.!\?]+/g )
}

var getUniqueWords = function(state) {
    for (var i = 0; i < state.words.length; i++) {
        if (state.uniqueWords.indexOf(state.words[i]) < 0) {
            state.uniqueWords.push(state.words[i])
        }
    }
}

var getWordCount = function(state) {
    state.wordCount = state.words.length
}

var getUniqueWordCount = function(state) {
    state.uniqueWordCount = state.uniqueWords.length
}

var getWordLengths = function(state) {
    for (var i = 0; i < state.words.length; i++) {
       state.wordLengths.push(state.words[i].length)
       console.log(state.wordLengths)
    }
}

var getAverageWordLength = function(state) { 
    var sum = state.wordLengths.reduce(function(a, b) {
        return a + b
    }, 0)
    state.averageWordLength = sum/state.wordLengths.length
}

var getSentenceLengths = function(state) {
    for (var i = 0; i < state.sentences.length; i++) {
        state.sentenceLengths.push(state.sentences[i].length)
    }
}

var getAverageSentenceLength = function(state) {
    var sum = state.sentenceLengths.reduce(function(a,b) {
       return a + b
    }, 0)
   state.averageSentenceLength = sum/state.sentenceLengths.length
}

// render functions

var renderWordCount = function(state, element) {
    $("dl").toggleClass('hidden')
    return element.append(state.wordCount)
}

var renderUniqueWordCount = function(state, element) {
    $("dl").toggleClass('hidden')
    return element.append(state.uniqueWordCount)
}

var renderAverageWordLength = function(state, element) {
    $("dl").toggleClass('hidden')
    return element.append(state.averageWordLength)
}

var renderAverageSentenceLength = function(state, element) {
    $("dl").toggleClass('hidden')
    return element.append(state.averageSentenceLength)
}

// event listener functions

$(function() {
    $('button').click(function() {
        event.preventDefault()
        getText(state)
        getWords(state)
        getSentences(state)
        getUniqueWords(state)
        getWordCount(state)
        getUniqueWordCount(state)
        getAverageWordLength(state)
        getSentenceLengths(state)
        getAverageSentenceLength(state)
        renderWordCount(state, $('.wordCount'))
        renderUniqueWordCount(state, $('.uniqueWordCount'))
        renderAverageWordLength(state, $('.averageWordLength'))
        renderAverageSentenceLength(state, $('.averageSentenceLength'))
    })
})
```

And here is the index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Text analyzer</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/4.2.0/normalize.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <main>
            <h1>Text analzyer</h1>
            <p>Paste in text below, submit, and get some basic stats back.</p>
            <form class="js-form">
                <div>
                    <label for="user-text">Text to analyze</label>
                    <textarea cols="60" rows="20" id="user-text" name="user-text" placeholder="What have you got to say?" required></textarea>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <button type="submit">Analyze it!</button>
                </div>
            </form>

            <dl class="hidden text-report">
                <dt>Word count</dt>
                <dd class="wordCount"></dd>

                <dt>Unique word count</dt>
                <dd class="uniqueWordCount"></dd>

                <dt>Average word length</dt>
                <dd class="averageWordLength"></dd>

                <dt>Average sentence length</dt>
                <dd class="averageSentenceLength"></dd>
            </dl>
        </main>
    </div>
    <script src="jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
<!-- <script src="app.js"></script> -->
    <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you!

P.S. If you have any ideas about structuring the app, all thoughts are welcome; I especially am concerned about the way I'm calling all the functions one after another in the ready function at the end. That seems kinda messy for some reason.

Comment: About structuring your app, the revealing prototype pattern could be a great choice in your case, more lecture in https://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/techniques-strategies-and-patterns-for-structuring-javascript-code-revealing-prototype-pattern

Comment: Thanks! That looks very useful...I'll read it ASAP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem lies in here:

```
$(function() {
    $('button').click(function() {
        event.preventDefault()
        getText(state) // <---at this point you are passing an object to set the text in.
        // state object but getText has some-thing which is not correct
        //.....other too
    })
})

var getText = function(state) {
    state.text = $('user-text').val() // <-----Here `user-text` is not a valid
    // html element and jquery doesn't recognize it.
    // So, You should change it to a valid css selector.
}
```

So, eventually you should use a Id selector:

```
$('#user-text').val()
```

As your html element has Id attribute:

```
<textarea cols="60" rows="20" 
          id="user-text" 
          name="user-text" 
          placeholder="What have you got to say?" required></textarea>
```

Comment: Thank you! Edited to reflect this.